# CSS How to override specific selectors in parent theme?

Tags: css, parent-child, css-selectors, overriding

I am creating a child theme of the Limon theme. This parent theme uses a lot of specific selectors such as

```
div#container_wrap {}
div#header ul#nav {}
div.page_heading {}
```

I am doing a fair bit of modifications so using "!important" is not an ideal solution.  What is the best way to override these div#ids without resorting to !important? Specific selectors are used extensively in the parent stylesheet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `!important`, you can always include your CSS after the one from the parent theme (and use the same selectors).

Or a more extreme approach if you can't do that for some weird reason - use even more specific selectors, eg:

```
body > div#container_wrap ...
```

Comment: `#container_wrap#container_wrap /* I mean it! */`

Comment: Thanks @minitech ! If I place the same selectors in the child stylesheet, doesnt that place it "after the parent theme" already? Or do you mean placing it in the parent stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

Put your **custom style** under the **original style**. Write like this:

```
div#container_wrap {} // original style
div#header ul#nav {} // original style
div.page_heading {} // original style
div#container_wrap {...} // custom style
div#header ul#nav {...} // custom style
div.page_heading {..} // custom style
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/9KeN8/

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. Would this modification have to be done in the parent stylesheet then?

Comment: Yes, but if you want separate stylesheet. Then define your custom stylesheet after the original one in the HTML page.

Comment: I would like to use a child stylesheet. Currently the stylesheets are defined in the header.php as follows.    

'<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />'

Is this what you meant? With this I can get some overrides to work and not others.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you are being overly specific with your CSS rules.  An `ID` is *the most specific* selector you can possibly use, so there's no need to qualify it by adding `div` of specifying a parent `ID`.

The following rules would be sufficient.

```
#container_wrap {}
#nav {}
.page_heading {}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Those codes are from a template I bought. I am trying to make modifications in a child theme and these overly specific selectors are reasons for my post here =)